# What's the difference between Node.js x86 and x64 installers for Windows?

Tags: windows, node.js

They both install node.exe into C:\Program Files **(x86)**... so I'm wondering what the actual difference is. I know that there is some because `node-sqlserver` module is failing on our machine and it does so in different ways for x86 and x64 versions of Node.

Can somebody explain the difference for me? Thanks.

Comment: fyi, now (circa 2015) the x64 version does not install to C:\Program Files (x86)...

Comment: If you have both installed, the one that gets called is the one first on the PATH environment variable...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The x64 installer installs the 64 bit version of node which is compiled against the 64 bit version of V8.  The node-sqlserver package is a native module which means it needs to be compiled against the matching version of node.  IE: It will fail if you are using a pre-compiled, 32 bit version of the module against the 64 bit version of node.

Other than the typical differences between 32 & 64 bit applications (larger address space, use of 8 bytes for addresses instead of 4 bytes), node doesn't differ between the two versions.

Comment: Hmm, there's a bug open about the installation path thing (which evidently does not happen on clean installs anymore, at least): https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2951